# HTML table tbody column widths not matching thead column widths after adding scrollbar using display: block

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I've been attempting to add a scrollbar to my tbody so that my thead sticks to the top. The scrollbar works, and my thead looks how I want it to, but the problem is that my tbody columns aren't "lining up" with the column widths being set in my thead anymore. My thead column widths are "auto-fitting" to the contents, and I want my tbody widths to match whatever is being set in the thead.

Removing "display: block" fixes this issue of course, but gets rid of my scrollbar, so I'm stuck. I've also tried adding 100% width to my tbody, as well as adding 100% width and display: block to my thead - These didn't change anything.

*Please see my edit at the bottom for another thing I've tried*

How do I add a scrollbar to my tbody without messing up my column widths?

[image]

```html
<table id="CmtRequests" class="table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-responsive" cellspacing="0">
    @* Header *@
    <thead>
        @* Filters row *@
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./Index" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark">Reset</a>
                <input formmethod="get" type="submit" value="Refresh" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" />
            </th>
            <th>
                <select class="form-control" asp-for="SupplierFilter" asp-items="Model.SupplierList"><option selected></option></select>
            </th>
            <th>
                <select class="form-control" asp-for="ReasonFilter" asp-items="Model.ReasonList"><option selected></option></select>
            </th>
            @*etc..*@
        </tr>
        @* Title row *@
        <tr>
            <th>
                Title
            </th>
            <th>
                Title
            </th>
            <th>
                Title
            </th>
            @*etc..*@
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @* Body *@
    <tbody style="overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; height:38vh; display:block;">
        @foreach (var item in Model.CmtRequests)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PartNo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SupplierNo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Priority)
                </td>
                @*etc..*@
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT:** I tried adding the following CSS class table-fixed, getting rid of all the style settings in my HTML above, and using it instead (from [this article](https://w3lessons.info/bootstrap-fixed-table-header-using-css/#Step_3_HTML_Code_for_Scrolling_Table_with_Fixed_Header)) and the scrollbar isn't appearing, so something else bigger must be going on:

```css
.table-fixed tbody {
    height: 38vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
.table-fixed tr,
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
    display: block;
}

    .table-fixed tr:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        visibility: hidden;
        clear: both;
    }

    .table-fixed tbody td,
    .table-fixed thead > tr > th {
        float: left;
    }
```

Comment: Did it work if yes mark as solved Thanks

Comment: Resolved! Found a very easy solution, [see this article for details](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/bartek-malanowski/901801).

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4>
                Fixed Header Scrolling Table 
              </h4>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-fixed">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-xs-2">#</th><th class="col-xs-8">Name</th><th class="col-xs-2">Points</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-xs-2">1</td><td class="col-xs-8">Mike Adams</td><td class="col-xs-2">23</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-xs-2">2</td><td class="col-xs-8">Holly Galivan</td><td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-xs-2">3</td><td class="col-xs-8">Mary Shea</td><td class="col-xs-2">86</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-xs-2">4</td><td class="col-xs-8">Jim Adams</td><td>23</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-xs-2">5</td><td class="col-xs-8">Henry Galivan</td><td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-xs-2">6</td><td class="col-xs-8">Bob Shea</td><td class="col-xs-2">26</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-xs-2">7</td><td class="col-xs-8">Andy Parks</td><td class="col-xs-2">56</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-xs-2">8</td><td class="col-xs-8">Bob Skelly</td><td class="col-xs-2">96</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-xs-2">9</td><td class="col-xs-8">William Defoe</td><td class="col-xs-2">13</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-xs-2">10</td><td class="col-xs-8">Will Tripp</td><td class="col-xs-2">16</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-xs-2">11</td><td class="col-xs-8">Bill Champion</td><td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-xs-2">12</td><td class="col-xs-8">Lastly Jane</td><td class="col-xs-2">6</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS: ==> width: 97%; does the trick

```
.table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr> th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks to create equal column widths using the bootstrap grid classes for every column. My width sizes vary per column (see screenshot) and I want my tbody columns to match the widths shown in my thead.

Comment: Do your math - size sm-1 means 8% sm-6 50% and so on - its pretty close to your 10% but only the grid classes ensure a flex design working. Use bootstrap either with all consequences or use your own design could start as a 90% copy of bootstrap. If fiddling with 100 manual adjustments an update of bootstrap may cause your design to break. Just talking form experience